# npm server build failed, The plugin "@parcel/transformer-sass" is not compatible with the current version of Parcel

Tags: npm, npm-start

I am having this issue when I do npm start, it keeps giving me this error, I did change the version in the package.json but still no affect, any advice how to build the server?
[image: @parcel/core: The plugin "@parcel/transformer-sass" is not compatible with the current version of Parcel. Requires "^2.7.0" but the current version is "2.0.1".]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: Not sure if it's still relevant (Find it by google) I solved it by installing a newer nodejs version, I use nvm to control the versions.